# Error executing "takeown" command from "runas" in batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, runas, file-ownership

I wrote a little program to automate:

1. **Taking own** of a file/folder for a specified User.
2. Get (for the same User) **FULL CONTROL** of the file/folder.

Now, it is well know that `takeown.exe` wants `cmd.exe` to be run as Administrator rights. So, to do in a batch file (most of the time called from a non-Administrator cmd window), I run:

```
call runas /noprofile /user:"!domain!\!runasUsr!" "cmd /k takeown /f ""!entity!"" /r"
```

However, even though I pass as `!runAsUsr!` a name which is contained in the Administrators Group, I get:

```
ERROR: the user currently connected does not have the ownership privileges on file/folder ...
```

I tried setting `!runAsUsr! = Administrators`, but unfortunately I do not remember the password (if I even set one...). For that, I could change from *computer manager* (or `net` command), but I do not well know how that command works, so I wouldn't mess things up.

But still, I do not understand why I get that error since the User I pass is within the Administrators group..

I see from computer manager that default account for computer administration is User:Administrator of the Group:Administrators, so this might be the problem. So, how to set the other account to have same rights?

I also tried

```
call runas /noprofile /user:"!domain!\Administrator" "cmd /k takeown /f ""!entity!"" /r"
```

getting following error:

```
ERROR RUNAS: impossible to execute - cmd /k takeown /f "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\css" /r
1327: restriction on user account do not allow this user to get access. 
For example, empty password field not allowed, access times restrictions or application of restriction criteria.
```

Comment: `runas` does as it says. But as there is no interactive user there is no-one to right click and choose Run As Administrator.

Comment: Well, there are many question on this topic, from which you can assert that `runas` is used within a batch file to launch (within another cmd window) another `command` with possibly elevated privileges. Also, what was not visible to you, this new cmd (*where I have the error messages*) appears, and the root folder is exactly "**C:\Windows\System32**" which is the one you're in when launching `cmd.exe` as Administrator..

Comment: Why doesn't your command work then?

Comment: If I had the answer maybe I wouldn't post the question here on SO, don't you think? :)

Comment: And takeown works for all users that have permission to take ownership.

Comment: If I run `takeown` from a `cmd` opened as Administrator, then it works fine. I try then, as you see in the question, to `runas Administrator` the command `takeown` and I get what you read. Maybe I was not clear enough, but did you get exactly what I am asking?

Comment: No I didn't as you can't elevate via runas.

Comment: So based on this, it is not possible to run `takeown` from a *normal* batch file. Is it?

Comment: Yes but but not with admin powers. Use Task Scheduler.

Comment: PS administration is http://serverfault.com and home computers http://superuser.com.

Comment: Also takeown takes user info. See takeown /?.